# How to format negative number with parenthesis using Struts2 message properties?

Tags: java, struts2, decimalformat

I have added the formatting pattern in the properties file as below :

1) format.properties

```
PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = {0,number,##0.00'%'}
```

2) balancesheet.jsp

I have formatted the profit percentage using `getText` as shown below :

```
 <TD class="amount">
     <s:property value="getText('PERCENTAGE_FORMAT',{#request.trade.profitPercentage})"  />
 </TD>
```

So, if percentage is `40.03` it is displayed as `40.03%` but when the percentage is negative say `-40.03` then how to display it as `(40.03)%` ? What should be the message format in the properties file?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for formatting negative numbers using message format as shown below :

```
PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = {0,number,##0.00'%';(##0.00)'%'}
```

The above format encloses all negative values in parenthesis.
That is, -40.03 will be displayed as (40.03)

Comment: Note that it isn't S2 specific, it's [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).